# .Net Framework API endpoint for file upload: Cannot make a request with Postman

Tags: c#, file-upload, postman

I'm creating a .Net framework (not DotNet Core) API endpoint to upload a file, and I'm not being able to debug the request in Visual Studio requesting from Postman. My app uses Swagger, and I can do a request with Swagger and debug with no problem, except that with Swagger I'm not able to display a "Select File" button, so I'm trying to use Postman.

My method, even though it's not finished yet, looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadVideo")]
public bool UploadVideo([FromBody] JObject pData, [FromUri] string videoTitle, [FromUri] string description,
                          [FromUri] short enterpriseId, [FromUri] int userId, [FromUri] int applicationId)
{
       string lFileBase64 = pData["file"]["File64Code"].ToString();
       string lFileName = pData["file"]["FileName"].ToString();
            Dictionary<string, string> exportParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       exportParams.Add("TYPE", ((int)RequestType.UsersImport).ToString());
       exportParams.Add("PFK_ENTERPRISE", enterpriseId.ToString());
       exportParams.Add("PK_USER", userId.ToString());
       exportParams.Add("PK_APPLICATION", applicationId.ToString());
       exportParams.Add("FILE_NAME", lFileName);

       Models.RequestLog requestLog = new Models.RequestLog();
       requestLog.Data = RequestLogService.ParseRequestParams(exportParams);
       requestLog.Type = RequestType.UsersImport;

       int requestId = RequestLogService.CreateRequestLog(enterpriseId, userId,
                 Mapper.Map<RequestLog>(requestLog));

       if (requestId > 0)
       {
         //update request status
         exportParams.Add("PK_REQUEST", requestId.ToString());
         requestLog.Id = requestId;
         requestLog.Status = RequestStatus.Sent;
         requestLog.Data = RequestLogService.ParseRequestParams(exportParams); ;
         RequestLogService.UpdateRequestLog(enterpriseId, userId,
                    Mapper.Map<RequestLog>(requestLog));

         string pCloudStorageAccount = AzureHelper.SelectAzureStorageAccount(enterpriseId);
         string pContainer = "docstmp" + AzureStorageSettings.AzureStorageContainer;
         MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(lFileBase64));
         Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
         lFileName = "UploadVideo_" + enterpriseId.ToString() + "_" + guid.ToString() + ".mp4";
         string urlAzure = AzureStorageHelpers.UploadFile(pCloudStorageAccount, pContainer, lFileName, myStream);
         exportParams.Add("URL", urlAzure);

         requestLog.Data = RequestLogService.ParseRequestParams(exportParams);
         RequestLogService.QueueRequest(enterpriseId, userId,
             Mapper.Map<RequestLog>(requestLog));
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }

       return true;
}
```

But the method is not relevant here, as my problem is Postman is not reaching the endpoint.

In the following pictures you can see details of the Postman request with the error thrown.

[image: Headers]

[image: Request]

What can I try next?

### Edit 1

Extra info get from Swagger that might be of help:

```
"/api/Catalogues/UploadVideo":{
   "post":{
      "tags":[
         "Catalogues"
      ],
      "operationId":"Catalogues_UploadVideo",
      "consumes":[
         "application/json",
         "text/json",
         "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ],
      "produces":[
         "application/json",
         "text/json"
      ],
      "parameters":[
         {
            "name":"pData",
            "in":"body",
            "required":true,
            "schema":{
               "type":"object"
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"videoTitle",
            "in":"query",
            "required":true,
            "type":"string"
         },
         {
            "name":"description",
            "in":"query",
            "required":true,
            "type":"string"
         },
         {
            "name":"enterpriseId",
            "in":"query",
            "required":true,
            "type":"integer",
            "format":"int32"
         },
         {
            "name":"userId",
            "in":"query",
            "required":true,
            "type":"integer",
            "format":"int32"
         },
         {
            "name":"applicationId",
            "in":"query",
            "required":true,
            "type":"integer",
            "format":"int32"
         }
      ],
      "responses":{
         "200":{
            "description":"OK",
            "schema":{
               "type":"boolean"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

### Edit 2

Already disabled SSL Certificate verification in Postman:

[image: Disabled SSL Verification in Postman]

Comment: You have a HTTPS (secure) connection which is encrypted.Postman cannot decrypt without the certificate (key).HTTPS uses TLS and the TLS is performed before the request is sent to obtain a key.TLS version can be found using a sniffer and must be TLS 1.2 or 1.3 (older version are obsolete).The server sends with TLS sends a certificate block which contains the names or certificate(s) and then client searches the available key names for a match. The certificates have an encryption method and usual reasons for TLS to fail is the certificate not load or OS is old and doesn't support encryption mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jdweng. I have already disabled SSL Certificate verification in Postman and the result is the same.

Comment: `string lFileBase64 = pData["file"]["File64Code"].ToString();` - ...are you _really_ trying to upload potentially **gigabyte-sized** video files as Base64 strings in a JSON body? _oh dear what has this become of this world?_

Comment: Binary files should be uploaded using either `multipart/form-data` (where ASP.NET can handle the streaming for you), or as their own **separate** `PUT` requests with raw binary bodies. Your code that uses `Convert.FromBase64String(lFileBase64)` is **just so horribly wrong** for so many reasons. Your code **will** cause the host server to run out of RAM for even the most trivial of uploaded files. Please, _please_ reconsider your entire approach, and remember: **Base64 is inappropriate for large binaries**.

Comment: That makes no sense.  Disabling Certificate check in Postman will work with HTTP (not secure) it won't work with HTTPS (secure).

Comment: Thanks for your comments @Dai. First of all, this code is not mine, it's a very old code I just copied to be able to debug, but you are right in what you say, in fact I will modify the upload login. In fact I have to upload files to Azure, so I'll look for a particular upload to work with BlobStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your postman, you are sending all data using a `form (body)`. Your endpoint is expecting all values, except the video, to be sent via the URL as query parameters.

In postman, add all your values to the `Params` tab, and add the video to the `Body` tab as you've done.

The attributes on the properties on your endpoint, you've stated this. `[FromBody]` means the form being sent with the `POST`. `[FromUri]` tells the endpoint it is expecting a value to be included in the URL itself.

This is also outlined in your swagger example:

***Body***

```
"name":"pData",
"in":"body" //<--this
```

***Query***

```
"name":"videoTitle",
"in":"query", //<--this
```

EDIT:
I suggest following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0) MS document. Use the correct methodology for uploading large files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Marius, the code I've pasted is not mine, is an old method I've taken just to be able to start debugging, but I need to update it. In fact I have to upload to Azure, so I'll look for an specific method to work with BlobStorage.